# Allowing my application to be used by other applications

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I would like to know how to allow my C# application to be used from others' own applications.

Is making the relevant classes public enough for this purpose? Shall they be able to put a reference in their projects to my .exe and use my public classes freely? Shall they only be able to use it from .NET applications?

What else should I take into account? Any security issues maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .Net dlls can be used by other .Net applications. You can separate the logic part of your code from the interface, and put the logic in "Library" projects that will be compiled as Dll files that can be used in a .Net application by adding references to them.

If you want to allow non .Net apps to used you can use COM Interop:

[Wikipedia - COM Interop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Interop)

[COM Interop C# Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645712%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

You can also use WCF services as CSharpVJ says.

Comment: Thank you. Creating separate dll files seems to be a good idea to start with. Then using COM or WCF... that needs further research.

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper WCF service and expose your exe application thru' those WCF services, and it will be available to almost all clients based on even other platforms like Java, Python, Ruby and more depending on which settings you use inside your WCF Service..

WCF provides a service based model to communicate with other applications based on .Net and other platforms.

WCF is explained at this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) in MSDN

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and link. At first sight it seems WCF makes much more than what I need, and it might be more difficult to learn than making a COM component, but it might be worth exploring.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just make the sourcecode public on https://github.com/ for example. 
That would other people allow to view and edit your sourcecode compeltly, which might be even better than a WCF service